# Cycle for to populate word template - data type error

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I am trying to do a simple code to populate a word file.
If i run the script with the For cycle below, VBA return me a runtime -13 error: data type not matched correctly about this code line `If CB & i = True Then`.
Any idea how I could solve to get CB1-CB2-CB3 and so on correctly to claim the different variables in the cycle?
Many thanks

```
Dim CB1 as integer
Dim CB2 as integer
Dim CB3 as integer
Dim CB4 as integer
If Data_entry.CheckBoxTomato.Value = True Then
CB1 = 0
else
CB1 = 1
end if
'the code repeats for CB2,CB3 and CB4
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 4
If CB & i = True Then
.Text = "MARK" & i
.Replacement.Text = "X"
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
'other sustitution
else
'other substitution
end if
next i
```

Comment: There is no `With` in your code - to what kind of object does `.text`, `.Replacement` belong?

Comment: Sorry, the code is inside this `With wd.Selection.Find`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA (and most other languages) don't work like this. When you write `If CB & i = True Then`, VBA will do the following:

- Look for a variable `CB`. If it doesn't exist and you don´t have `Option Explicit` set, VBA will create it on the fly as an empty variable.
- Concatenate the *content* of the variable with `i`. Assuming that you didn't declare `CB`, the result will be a string, eg the string `1` (which is not the number 1).
- Now it will try to compare that string with the value `True`. One is a String, one is a Boolean, and you can't compare those - you will get a type mismatch error.

Your idea is to have 4 variables and you want to check those variables in your loop. Best to do this is not to declare them as 4 single variables but to use an Array. You can access the members of the variable using the index (the "number"), with is added to the variable name in parentheses.

```
Dim ch(1 to 4) As Boolean  ' Consider to choose a more meaningfull name!
```

Now you can use them like this:

```
If Data_entry.CheckBoxTomato.Value = True Then
  ch(1) = True
Else
  ch(1) = False
End IF
```

However, that can be written shorter, no need for the `If`:

```
ch(1) = Data_entry.CheckBoxTomato.Value
```

And when you check the content, you would use

```
For i = 1 To 4  
    If cb(i) Then ' use the i´th member of the array.
    ' Note: Some prefer to write If cb(i) = True Then
        .Text = "MARK" & i
        .Replacement.Text = "X"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: If I could I would upvote this 5 times - very good explanation!

Comment: Many thanks. I modified the code according to your huge answer and now it works properly. I though there was some kind of issues related to my fault to code properly. Definitely, I need to study a little bit. Extremely helpful explanation.