# variables in variables VBA

Tags: vba, loops, variables

number 1 to 100 are stored in column A and I want to declare variables where N1 = 1, N2 = 2, ... N100 = 100. But I am always stuck. Here is my VBA code:

```
Sub one_hundred()
For y = 1 To 100
    "N" & "y" = y
Next y
End Sub
```

Comment: This will not work - use Arrays. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73167188/7599798

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cycle for to populate word template - data type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73166733/cycle-for-to-populate-word-template-data-type-error)

Comment: No, not really... I think two problems are different

Comment: Why not? What is unclear? `"N" & "y"` is an expression and evolves into a string like `N1` at runtime. No way to force the compiler (that is triggered at Compile time) to use that string as a variable name. Just declare your variable as `Dim N(1 to 100) as Long` and write `N(y) = y`.

Comment: Maybe you need to explain, for what you need this routine ...